# Cant get input text boxes and buttons the same size

Tags: html, css, forms, submit-button

I'm trying to create a form with input text boxes and submit boxes being perfectly lined up and equal in size. However for some reason the submit button is a few pixels out of alignment and I cant figure out the cause.

The elements are the same size and I've tried removing margins and paddings but havent been able to resolve the issue.

I've created a simple jfiddle to illustrate my problem. 
https://jsfiddle.net/peacefulgoldfish/d50h7n9p/26/

Appreciate any help and advice on this.

html

```
<div>
<form>
<input>
<br>
<input>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

css

```
#div{

  width:100%;
}

form{

  text-align: center;

}

input {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 10%;
  width: 50%;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the box-sizing of the input to make all of them equal width. Here whats your updated CSS should look like:

```
div {
  font-size:0;
}
#form{  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
input {
  height: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: In that case, you may want to add font-size:0; to div and font-size: 14px; to your input.

Answer (score 1):

Update your css may be this can help you.

```
#div{

  width:100%;
}

form{

  text-align: center;

}

input {
    height: 10%;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using flex

```
form{

  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-items:center

}
```

But you have to deal with extra space if you dont need it

Answer (score 0):

Box Sizing is the only valid solution for this problem. My personal suggestion is to use `box-sizing: border-box;` for all elements.

Like This :

- {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

Here `*` selects all elements in the current DOM.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#form {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  height: 10%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
      <input>
      <br>
      <input>
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is wrapper

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>

<form>
<input><br/>
<input><br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this code does not work when my form is inside a div element, see my updated jsfiddle